# Can exception be perfectly replaced by if.. else?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm new to programming and I have a conceptual question.

That is, can "exception" be perfectly replaced by "if.. else" ?

I know "exception" is to handling some exceptional conditions that might cause error or crash.

But we also use "if.. else" to ensure the correctness of value of variables, don't we?

Or "exception" can really be replaced by "if.. else", but using "exception" has other benefits(like convenience?)

Thank you, and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Are you referring to `try-catch` when you say `exception` or just `exception` itself?

Comment: sorry.. but i can't catch the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your questions relate to Python, so here is an answer based on that fact.

In Python, it is idiomatic (or "pythonic") to use `try`-`except` blocks. We call this ["EAFP": Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp).

In C, where there were no exceptions, it was usual to ["LBYL": Look before you leap](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl), resulting in lots of `if (...)` statements.

So, while you can LBYL, you should follow the idioms of the language in which you are programming: using exceptions for handling exceptional cases and `if`-statements for conditionals.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helps a lot! And I think the existence of these two coding styles implicitly means "exception" can be perfectly replaced by "if.. else" roughly, right?

Comment: One big difference is that exceptions can be caught further up the call stack, where as checking with an `if` is much more localised.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference between exceptions and "if..else" is that exceptions pass up the call stack:  an exception raised in one function can be caught in a caller any number of frames up the stack.  Using "if" statements doesn't let you transfer control in this way, everything has to be handled in the same function that detected the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the answer is yes, exceptions can be perfectly replaced by if-else.  Many languages, C for example, have no native notion of exceptions that can be thrown and caught.

The primary advantage of exceptions is code readability and maintainability.  They serve a different purpose than if-else.  Exceptions are for exceptional conditions, while if-else is for program flow.

See [this excellent article](http://hi.baidu.com/tianyistar/blog/item/c6e48f44154a9f4c500ffeef.html) explaining the difference.

Comment: Note: domanokz asks a relevant question, and my answer assumes you are talking about exceptions in a java/python/javascript sense.

Comment: exceptions can be perfectly replaced by if-else? That's ridiculous, -1

Comment: So if I call some random library function which has code if(x==1) { throw new FileNotFoundException(); }, how would you reproduce that? Dig into the source of the library and repeat the exact same code? How is that considered a perfect replacement??

Comment: As I understood the question (perhaps wrongly, but based on the tag programming-languages -- and no tags referring to Java, or libraries or anything else) it referred to a general question about constructing a programming language.  Your interpretation is completely fair.  Obviously if you want to use libraries that use exceptions, you need... exceptions.

Comment: The key word is perfect, even if you aren't using 3rd party libraries and you want to pass something up the call stack you would need to put these if/else into each function of the call stack based on return value. I don't consider that perfect; I guess we'll agree to disagree...

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of branch conditions to manage.  In theory, exceptions aren't necessary for perfect code, but perfect code does not exist in real life.  Exceptions are a well-established mechanism for dealing with problems in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 0):

The old way for handling an error from a function looks something like this:

```
int result = function_returns_error_code();
if (result != GOOD)
{
    /* handle problem */
}
else
{
   /* keep going */
}
```

The problem with this solution (and others like it - using if-else) is that if there is a real problem, and the programmer does not properly handle it with an if...else (if the function returns an error code indicating major problems, but the programmer forgets about it), it is left ignored. With an exception, it goes further and further up the call stack ) until it is either handled or the program quits.

Further, it is tedious to check for error codes in functions, or pass a parameter into which to put an error code. It is simpler, cleaner, and better to use exceptions, for maintainability and abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

In most high-level languages working with exceptions is often more efficient than if-else because you avoid multiple validation. eg:

`if value is not 0 then print 10 / value`

In most interpreters `10 / value` will internally test whether `value` is a valid divider before using it so you've actually tested for the same problem twice. In some cases the exception may come all the way up from hardware so no software validation is happening at all.

On the other hand:

`try print 10 / value ... catch exception`

Will only test whether value is valid once. Furthermore there's a good chance the test will be better optimised than your own code and more capable of handling truly unexpected conditions (like out of memory errors).